# how to exchange image by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i having a main image and when i click on that image a modal box open in which there are 3 images . So when i click one of the image in modal box it has to swap with the main image i dont have any idea how to do that . please help me my code goes here

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img responsive curtain1"id="1" src="curtain.jpeg" ></a>
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id = "1">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;" alt="one">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id = "2">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;"alt="two">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id = "3">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;"alt="three">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap the image you need to just replace the image path with current one.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <img class="img responsive curtain1" id="mainImage" src="curtain.jpeg" >
</a>

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="1">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;" alt="one" class="image1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="2">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;"alt="two" class="image2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="3">
    <img src="curtaina1.jpg"style="height:35%;width:45%;"alt="three" class="image3">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For swapping please use below jQuery :

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
})
```

Please try this code.